# Elementos con URL remota

Tags: css, variables, url

estoy tratando de encontrar una solucion para la siguiente cuestion, tengo un sitio que llama a un css que se encuentra en otro dominio, al llamarlo todos los valores de url para imagenes como ser background y otros se asocian a la url del host del estilo y no al host del sitio que solicita el css

como ejemplo pongo

http://myserver.com/css/estilo.css

en el sitio test1.myserver.com que tengo llamo a ese estilo con

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://myserver/css/estilo.css">
```

dentro de estilo.css tengo

```
.main{
background-image: 'img/image.png';
}
```

esto hace que en lugar de traer la imagen desde test1.myserver.com/img/image.png lo trae desde myserver.com/img/image.png

rompiendome la cabeza tratando de encontrar una solucion parecida a la siguiente, pero no encontre la forma de hacerlo, el siguiente codigo estaria alojado en server.com/css/estilo.css.

```
:root {
  --direc: url('https://test1.myserver.com/img/');
}

.main {
  background-image: var( --direc ) + 'image.png';
}
```

pero creo que en css no se puede concatenar de esta manera.

espero puedan ayudarme!

Gracias!

Comment: **1**. puedes crear un fichero con imágenes idénticas `myserver.com/img`. **2**. puedes sobreescribir solo las reglas donde aparecen imágenes

Comment: ¿y por qué no usas rutas absolutas?

Comment: @blonfu si quiere tener imágenes diferentes dependiendo del dominio que carga el fichero, las rutas absolutas no van a funcionar (porque serían las mismas para todos).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya, supongo que solo quiere cambiar la *custom property* con el dominio pero no se pueden concatenar strings en css.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tenías en mente es un buen intento, aunque no va a funcionar por varios motivos.

Primero porque la concatenación en CSS se hace sin el `+`; simplemente poniendo los valores uno detrás del otro sin ningún operador (los espacios en blanco se ignoran, debes añadirlos como cadena entre las variables). Por ejemplo:

```css
div::before {
  --saludo: "Hola";
  --nombre: "Álvaro";
  content:  var(--saludo) " " var(--nombre);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Otro problema del código es que, incluso si la concatenación en CSS se hiciera con el `+`, la variable `--direc` contiene el resultado de la función `url()`, concatenándole una cadena haces que el valor no sea válido, y por tanto tampoco esa propiedad.

Pero el problema principal es que, aunque muchas funciones en CSS van a interpolar los valores que se encuentren, eso no va a ocurrir con `url()`. **La función `url()` toma todo el contenido como si fuera una url y no procesa los posibles valores o atributos que  uses entre los paréntesis**. Al usar `var()` dentro de los paréntesis, la URL generada será incorrecta. No se está haciendo `url(` con el valor de `var(--nombre)` dentro seguido de `)`, sino que se intenta validar la cadena "var(--nombre)" como URL y no funciona.

La idea básica es: no puede hacerse sólo con CSS (al menos de la manera en la que lo estás haciendo). Aquí te dejo algunas alternativas:

1. **Redefine los estilos en un nuevo fichero**: Si sabes las reglas que van a necesitar reescribirse, redefínelas en un fichero CSS aparte con las nuevas rutas e importa ese fichero después de importar el otro.

   Ventajas: es 100% CSS y fácil de implementar.
   Inconvenientes: debes conocer las reglas y es difícil de mantener si cambian.
2. **Preprocesa/canaliza el fichero CSS**: en lugar de importar el fichero CSS, lee su contenido y sustituye unos dominios por otros. Esto lo podrías hacer con un lenguaje en el lado del servidor o con JavaScript/AJAX. Alternativamente, simplemente lee el contenido y sírvelo como propio (desde el lado del servidor) entonces las rutas serían relativas al dominio que importa en lugar del importado.

   Ventajas: más robusto (sigue funcionando si cambian las reglas).
   Inconvenientes: algo más lento y requiere conocimientos aparte de CSS.